# Generate PDF with Latin/Chinese/Japanese characters

Tags: javascript, pdf, jspdf, chinese-locale, pdfmake

I tried to generate a PDF in client-side using jsPDF and pdfmake javascript libraries supporting Latin/Chinese/Japanese characters.

The problem with jsPDF is that it hasn't got UTF-8 support and it's not possible to add a custom font. The problem that I have with pdfmake is that I cannot add a font with more than 95 glyphs.

I've also try to use a canvas with the text and add it to the PDF using the fromHTML function (jsPDF) but I need small font-size text and the quality of the canvas is very poor.

I also need to include charts in the PDF but I've already had that working using Google Charts API (client-side).

The website is write in classic ASP.

Can you give me some advice, please?